# surges in my toilet

Tags: toilet

My toilet surges at night and the water heater is fine and my pipes are fine as well.no pressure regulation problem but my toilet surges at night.before it becomes a problem what can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "surges"?

Comment: Somehow this sounds like the beginning of a Dr. Seuss book. "My toilet it surges and gurgles at night; the pressure it varies and gives me a fright"...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that by surge you mean that you hear the toilet come on for a short time and then go back off. This behavior can sometimes even rattle the water lines if the time the toilet is on is a short time.

Your toilet may very well be doing this during the day time but is not noticed with all the regular day time activity and sounds.

The cause of this behavior is likely to be toilet tank that is leaking at a very low rate down into the toilet bowl. This can be due to a flapper valve that needs replacement, a flapper valve that is not closing and sealing properly or one that may having its pull chain getting stuck and holding the flapper from closing 100%. Since flapper valves generally need periodic replacement the best fix for this is to replace the flapper with a fresh new one.

Another possibility is that the float valve is adjusted too set the water level too high that it just comes up over the overflow tube. If the valve shuts off in this condition surface tension of the water can occur allowing the water to be statically a small amount above the overflow tube. Over time the surface tension can break allowing water down the tube and re-activate of an over sensitive float valve and causing the re-fill action to occur. The fix for this would be to re-adjust the float valve. If you have a very old toilet valve assembly, especially one of the old fashioned type with the float ball on the end of a long arm, it may be time to replace it with a more modern plastic type with the float integrated right on the valve riser pipe assembly. These are not very expensive and can be changed out in a short time.

There are other toilet type faults that can lead to the the slow leak. A crack in the lower part of the overflow tube for example. I have even seen several instances of fine particulate (sand) getting trapped inside the needle valve part of the float valve assembly. This can cause the needle valve seat in the diaphragm part of the assembly to leak over time and cause the valve to come on periodically for a short period of time. Sometimes this can be fixed by opening up the flush valve assembly and cleaning it out. More often is easier to just replace the whole valve assembly. Like I said they are not that costly.